# How to call an intent of a 3rd party app in Android

Tags: android, apktool

I'd like to call the services of a third party app - i.e. call from my app.

I used `apktool` to decode the app and have the INTENT name.

But how can I figure out the parameters it expects?

Thanks.

Comment: Ask the developers of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the intents are not specified with `android:exported="true"` in manifest, you can't launch them through your app.
2. If intents are described as exported, you should read the decoded app java intent receive method to understand its parameters.